# Why does my application only return the path when replacing the <a> tag with <NavLink> or <Link>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use version:

[image]

```
<div className="topnav">
  <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active" exact={true}>
    Home
  </NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/todo" activeClassName="active" exact={true}>
    Todo
  </NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="active">
    About
  </NavLink>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
</div>
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <>
    <Navigation />
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/todo">
        <TodoApp />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </>
</BrowserRouter>
```

With the above application, when I use the `<a>` tag it works fine. When I replace it with `<Link>` or `<NavLink>`, my application only returns the link but does not re-render the application. How to fix it?